# AWS Lambda cannot connect to Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-parameter-store

I have a AWS `Lambda` (java) and I try to do a test in order to retrieve a password stored on Parameter Store.
Here is my piece of code:

```
GetParameterRequest parameterRequest = new GetParameterRequest();
        AWSSimpleSystemsManagement client = AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        parameterRequest.withName("my-password-key")
                .setWithDecryption(true);
        GetParameterResult parameterResult = client.getParameter(parameterRequest);
        password = parameterResult.getParameter().toString();
```

The `security group` (and the `NACL`) associated with my lambda has all inbound and outbound open (any port and any IP address).

My lambda run inside a private subnet.

When I execute the lambda (triggered by an API Gateway event) I have the following error:

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to ssm.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 [ssm.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com] failed: connect timed out: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException
```

Since the error is about an timeout error, I think it's not a role problem.

I have no idea where to look.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

C.C.

Comment: Can you check if you have internet access from the private subnet? You should use a NAT gateway / NAT instance to connect to internet from private subnet.

Comment: I will check that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internet access is required when calling an AWS API.

There are two ways to give a Lambda function access to the Internet:

- Do not attach the Lambda function to a VPC, or
- Attach the Lambda function to a private subnet and configure the private subnet to route Internet-bound traffic through a NAT Gateway (or NAT instance) in a public subnet

So, if the Lambda function does not need to access any resources in the VPC, simply **remove it from the VPC**. If it *does* need access, then **add a NAT Gateway**.

Comment: It means that in order to connect to the parameter store do I need to go out on the Internet ? It is a public endpoint (like api gateway enpoint ?) ?

Comment: Yes, all AWS API endpoints are on the Internet, but you can sometimes use a VPC Endpoint instead, which gives access directly from the VPC.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: I spent an entire day troubleshooting a lambda that worked perfectly on my local machine, but would not succeed when deployed to AWS. This was the exact solution for me. Thank you.