# lambda timeout when calling parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that calls the parameter store to retrieve a credential. The code is as follows:

```
import boto3
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
parameter = ssm.get_parameter(Name='credentials', WithDecryption=True)
print(parameter['Parameter']['Value'])
```

I have given AmazonSSMFullAccess to the lambda role. The lambda has a VPC which later I'll use it to connect to a Redshift database without public access. The inbound and outbound rules are as follows:
[image]

There is a post [AWS Lambda cannot connect to Parameter Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257379/aws-lambda-cannot-connect-to-parameter-store) which mentions that if the lambda requires VPC, then add a NAT gateway.

In the lambda subnet route table: [image], there seems to be already a route that goes to the internet?

But I am still getting lambda time-out errors :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> there seems to be already a route that goes to the internet?

Sadly, it **does not**. It seems you placed your lambda in a public subnet with route to internet gateway (IGW). However, you have to use **private subnet** with a route to NAT gateway. IGW and NAT are two different things. Have a look at this AWS guide how to make it work:

- [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Alternatively, you can setup [VPC interface endpoint for Paramter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-create-vpc.html). Then you don't need internet access for your Lambda function.

Comment: thanks! In the end i created the VPC interface endpoint for parameter store and it worked!